# How do I find out the file system of a Network Drive from my Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, network-shares

I am trying to find out whether a networked external hard drive is using FAT32 or NTFS for its file system.

Is there a way to do this through the GUI or can I do it via Terminal. It is definitely mounted as I can see it in /Volumes/ but I don't have sufficient Unix knowledge to find this out.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The information is available through `/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app` or via the command line utility `diskutil info /Volumes/<VolumeName>`.

UPDATE: Actually, those only provide information about file systems on locally attached disks and disk images.  For other types of mountable file systems, you can use the `mount` command to get information about all mounted file systems including the file system types.  Or, if you are just interested in one particular file type, you can use `df -t`.

```
$ mount
[...]
a.net:/srv/music on /Volumes/music/music (nfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
[...]
$ df -t nfs
Filesystem        512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  Mounted on
a.net:/srv/music   227067200 208996288   6536576    97%    /Volumes/music/music
```

Comment: thanks. I already tried the Disk Utility through the GUI and it only showed my Macintosh HD and my External HD, not the networked drive. I will try the terminal way when i get home.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Networked file systems do not show up in Disk Utility or diskutil.  See updated answer.

Comment: NFS isn't the underlying file system, just the protocol used to make it available via the network.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly, the file server hides it implicitly.

But you can guess: if all you need to know is whether it's FAT or NTFS, just copy a file >2GB on it - if it fails, it's probably FAT which cannot handle files >2GB. There are also some differences in how many files per folder, allowed characters and so on (have a look at the file systems wikipedia pages).

Comment: FAT32's most annoying restriction (back then) is probably the easiest solution.